# Fermat's Last Theorem: implications (there is no new proof)

Tags: number-theory, math-history

I am not experienced in Number Theory but what I know is that some results of this filed are applicable in other areas, e.g. algebra. For sure FLT made (and makes) people be interested in Number Theory leading to the development of new methods which can be themselves applied not only for the proof of FLT (like financial problems motivated somehow development of stochastic analysis). I am interested - if there are applications or implications of FLT itself?

More precisely: if the fact "for each $n\geq3$ there are no integer solutions of $a^n+b^n=c^n$" leads to solutions of problems which are not in the field of Number Theory?

I would specify that I wonder about some problems which are already formulated: since FLT is known for more then 300 years I am pretty sure that there were formulated hypothesis which follow from FLT directly (if there are such hypothesis *not* in the field of Number Theory).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Actually, FLT has very few consequences even in Number Theory. Its importance has always been in the methods that were developed in the effort to settle it, and what else could be done with those methods.

Comment: The Riemann hypothesis is quite different. Many results on number theory is based on the "solution" of Riemann hypothesis (common belief is the hypothesis is true.)

Answer (score 2):

I've read a number theory paper (on [Heron Triangles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heronian_triangle)) that used FLT. See Proposition 14 of [this](http://calhoun.nps.edu/public/bitstream/handle/10945/38838/Heron2013.pdf?sequence=1) paper.

Comment: I don't think this example is very compelling since it only uses the solution of the Diophantine equation $a^2 = x^2 + y^2$.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps. But you can consider this for fun in the meantime while you search for something significant. More of a "nuking the mosquito"

To prove  $2^\frac{1}{n}$ is an irrational number when $n\ge3$.

$$2^\frac{1}{n}=\frac{p}{q}$$

$$p^n=q^n+q^n$$
which contradicts the $FLT$, therefore proving $2^\frac{1}{n}$ is indeed irrational.

On a side note, $FLT$ is not strong enough to prove the irrationality of $2^\frac{1}{n}$ for case $n=2$